# $3$ sets of values. Two possible pairs form perfect lines, proof that the third pair will as well?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Let's say I have $3$ sets of real numbers. If the first and second set are plotted as $x-y$ points and form a straight line, and the first and third plotted also form a straight line, is there a proof or some way to show that the second and third set plotted will also form a straight line?

Comment: Welcome to the community! It would be better if you show your try at the question and where you're stuck.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I wish I could, but this is outside my field of expertise. I don't even know the proper notation, vocabulary, or tags to use to better express my question. The concept just seems intuitive to me, and the best I can do is generate sets to test the idea, but that's far from something that resembles an actual proof, which I need in order to justify some statistical tests I want to perform on some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I have 3 sets of real numbers.

Let those be $x_k, y_k, z_k\,, \; k \ge 0\,$.

> If the first and second set are plotted as x-y points and form a straight line,

This means that $\displaystyle\frac{y_k-y_0}{x_k-x_0}=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$ for all $k \ge 1\,$.

> and the first and third plotted also form a straight line,

This means that $\displaystyle\frac{z_k-z_0}{x_k-x_0}=\frac{z_1-z_0}{x_1-x_0}$ for all $k \ge 1\,$.

> is there a proof or some way to show that the second and third set plotted will also form a straight line?

$\displaystyle\frac{z_k-z_0}{y_k-y_0} = \;\ldots \;\;?$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure of the proper notation or how to relate the sets to the linear equation, but I see it now, and how they relate algebraically to show what I expected to be the case.